# Unable to access my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I keep getting the error cannot set property '0' of undefined at create2DArray.

Mind explaining what's wrong with the logic here? I know it's a rookie mistake cause I still haven't gotten the hang of arrays.

```
const ROW = 10;
const COL = 11;
const SIZE = 64;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var surface = canvas.getContext("2d");
const image = new Image();
image.src = "box_image.png";

//creating a tile
function Box() {
    this.xaxis = 0;
    this.yaxis = 0;
    this.img = image;
}

create2DArray();

//creating map
var map = [];

function create2DArray() {
    for (var i=0; i < ROW; i++){
        map[i] = [];
        for (var j=0; j<COL; j++){
            map[i][j] = new Box();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `create2DArray()` **before** you initialize `map`.

Comment: as followup on @Pointy, this can happen because your function is manipulating a global variable that it should be given as a parameter instead, so make rewrite things to `function created2DArray(map) { ... }` and you will reasonably not hit this again (and when you do, the error will be much more obvious). If a function needs to manipulate a thing, pass that thing in. Don't trust it to exist in some higher scope.

Comment: Your code is basically `var map = undefined; create2DArray(); map = [];`

Comment: @Pointy what a point

Comment: @Pointy I knew it was something dumb. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of variable hoisting here.

The way you declared map, it is declared and initialized after the create2DArray call.

There are two catches here

1. Variables that are declared and defined anywhere in your function, they get hoisted to the top of the function, with declarations but not initialization.
   In your case, only *var map;* gets hoisted but not *var map = []*
2. functions always get hoisted no matter where they are delcared and hence even though method declaration is at the end, you are still able to call.
   But when you have a function expression, you will run into the same issue as createArray is not defined, if you have something like this.

   ```
   var create2DArray = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
           map[i] = [];
           for (var j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
             map[i][j] = new Box();
           }
     }
   }
   ```

```js
const ROW = 10;
const COL = 11;
const SIZE = 64;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var surface = canvas.getContext("2d");
const image = new Image();
image.src = "box_image.png";

//creating a tile
function Box() {
  this.xaxis = 0;
  this.yaxis = 0;
  this.img = image;
}

var map = [];

create2DArray();

//creating map


function create2DArray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    console.log("Creating Box", i);
    map[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
      
      map[i][j] = new Box();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

More about [Variable and Function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_hoisting)